# Form/Data Body returns [Object: null prototype] { id: 'df4f8rfrf' } in nestjs / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I follow this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Bk3.png) but it's not working for me. When I am trying to pass form data to my database, My controller returns

> categories: [Object: null prototype] {
> id: '3a0e56cc-5670-4dcc-9bbd-8ef38d2b1535'   }

But I don't know the reason.
The data should return like this:
[image]

This is my code :

```
 @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  async create(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto,
  ) {
    console.log('createItemDto', createItemDto);
    try {
      const item = await this.itemService.create(createItemDto);
      if (item) {
          return {
            statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
            message: 'Item created successfully',
            item,
             };
      }

    } catch (error) {
      return {
        message: error.detail,
      };
    }
  }
```

This is what my error looks like :
I really need your all help. Because I have no idea about this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this but I did something like this:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(abc)); // abc = [Object: null prototype] { id: '123' }

console.log(obj); // { id: '123' }
```